# jQuery changing content inside Div

Tags: jquery

**Hi**

I am having difficulty in finding answer to my question most likely because my code  is not being written in the correct manner.

I am making main web page with 5 different options to choose from and I want to make that when user clicks on options id displays different content inside Div container. So far I managed to code two options to show different content on click but not able to do the same on third, fourth and fifth option.
Please see code bellow and if not to much to ask please can you advise me.
ps: I am total beginner at developing so please do not lough to much :).

So first one below is my HTML:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('#one').on('click', function() {
    if ($('.container2').css('display') != 'none') {
      $('.container').show().siblings('div').hide();
    }
  });
});



jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('#two').on('click', function() {
    if ($('.container').css('display') != 'none') {
      $('.container2').show().siblings('div').hide();
    }
  });
});

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('#three').on('click', function() {
    if ($('????????').css('display') != 'none') {
      $('.container3').show().siblings('div').hide();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body class="body">
  <header class="mainHeader">


    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a id="one" href="#">ONE</a>
        </li>
        <!--class="active"-->
        <li><a id="two" href="#">TWO</a>
        </li>
        <li><a id="three" href="#">THREE</a>
        </li>
        <li><a id="four" href="#">FOUR</a>
        </li>
        <li><a id="five" href="#">FIVE</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>


  <div class="container">
    <div class="mainContent">
      <p>TEXT and ETC</p>
    </div>
  </div>



  <div class="container2" style="display: none;">
    <div class="content2">
      <p>TEXT and ETC</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container3" style="display: none">
    <div class="mainContent3">
      <p>TEXT and ETC</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container4" style="display: none">

  </div>

  <div class="container5" style="display: none">

  </div>
```

So when I click on 'one' option it shows content inside Div container one. When I click 'two' option it shows different content that I coded for container 2 option 'two' but when I click on option 'three' it displays container 3 content but after clicked I m not able to go back to 2 or 1 options.

I hope this is not to much to ask. Thanks in advance.

Comment: no need for seperate `jQuery(document).ready(function($)` 

just place in single .ready() function, and please create jsFiddle

Comment: What is this `$('????????')` from `if ($('????????').css('display') != 'none') {`?

Comment: I was not sure what to put in so I type $('?????????'). do not pay attention to this. I will try the below code from Developer

Comment: Also thanks lazy rabbit for a tip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this helps

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".menu").click(function() {
   var selectedContainerId = $(this).attr("data-target");
 
   //show the selected container
   var selectedContainer = $(selectedContainerId);
   selectedContainer.show();
 
   //hide others
   $('div[id*="container_"]').not(selectedContainer).hide();
 
  });
});
```

```css
div[id*="container_"] {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<header class="mainHeader">
  <nav>
<ul>
  <li><a class="menu" data-target="#container_one" href="#">ONE</a></li>
  <!--class="active"-->
  <li><a class="menu" data-target="#container_two" href="#">TWO</a></li>
  <li><a class="menu" data-target="#container_three" href="#">THREE</a></li>
  <li><a class="menu" data-target="#container_four" href="#">FOUR</a></li>
  <li><a class="menu" data-target="#container_five" href="#">FIVE</a></li>
</ul>
  </nav>
</header>


<div id="container_one">
  <div class="mainContent">
<p> TEXT and ETC 1 </p>
  </div>
</div>



<div id="container_two">
  <div class="mainContent">
<p> TEXT and ETC 2 </p>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="container_three">
  <div class="mainContent">
<p> TEXT and ETC 3 </p>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="container_four">
  <div class="mainContent">
<p> TEXT and ETC 4 </p>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="container_five">
  <div class="mainContent">
<p> TEXT and ETC 5 </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you Developer I will try this.

Comment: figured out wohoo!! menu id's have to match container id's... Thanks @Developer

Comment: Glad I helped! Happy coding...

Comment: just wondering if you mentoring beginners at all?

Comment: @Matt - Sorry for late response, I got pretty much held up with my work. I do mentor beginners but only inside my company. jQuery is easy to learn, I would recommend you to download one of those jQuery cheat sheets (for eg, https://makeawebsitehub.com/jquery-mega-cheat-sheet/) and start trying out different selectors and methods. There will be 'n' number of ways to achieve something in jQuery, just to show you that, I have updated the code above. please have a look. IMO the above code is more elegant than the prev one.

Comment: @@Developer thank you for you support.