# Changing content inside single div with images on slider

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider

I've tried many codes from multiple answers around internet, but none actually worked..

**If images on slider started swapping content inside single .div, the slider didn't work or was collapsing..**

I've succeed once, but then changed single thing and when I went back with ctrl+z, it didn't work back again. That got me so angry and hopeless, that I decided to write here.

**So this is my 'precious' slider in a snippet. I want single image to be clickable and display different content, which would appear in a .div below, and make other content dissapear.**

*Side note: When I used this solution with jquery [jQuery changing content inside Div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41505126/jquery-changing-content-inside-div)
It made the slider once work, then I added 1 line, then went back, and at once it was not working. Which was really strange - this never happened to me, that the code was the same, but didn't work second time. The possible code for .div content swapping, must've been compatible with the slider.*

I am a newbie and know nothing about jquery or javascript, so please be considerate!-->

[Peek of my website with working slider - same code as below. As I said, I'd want images to be clickable, and change content inside a .div, that would be settled under slider. Each image is different content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pd9zp.jpg)

```js
"use strict";



var SLIDER_CLASS = 'slider';
var DELAY = 4000;
var sliders = document.getElementsByClassName(SLIDER_CLASS);


initSliders();


function slideAll () {
  for (var i=0; i<sliders.length; i++) {
    if (!sliders[i].getAttribute('data-slider-paused')) {
      slide(sliders[i]);
    }
  }
}

function slide (slider) {
    slider.sliderIndex++;
    slider.children[0].style.marginLeft = -slider.clientWidth*(slider.sliderIndex%slider.children.length) + 'px';
}

function initSliders () {
  for (var i=0; i<sliders.length; i++) {
    var slider = sliders[i];
    
    slider.sliderIndex = 1;
    slider.onclick = clickSlider;
  }
  setInterval(slideAll, DELAY);
}

function clickSlider (e) {
  if (!e.target.classList.contains(SLIDER_CLASS)) {
    return;
  }
  
  var bounds = this.getBoundingClientRect();
  if (e.clientX-bounds.left < bounds.width/2) {
    this.sliderIndex+=sliders.length;
  } slide(e.target);
}
```

```css
/*SLIDER*/
#sliderbox {
  margin-top:-10%;
  min-height:100vh;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
 }


.slider {
  width:900px;
  height:300px;
  background-color:none;
  display:flex;
  overflow:hidden;
  position:relative;
  margin:0px 0;
  border:1px solid #FF0
}

.slider:before,
.slider:after {
  content:'\27A4';
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  font-size:400%;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
  
  cursor:pointer;
  color:#FF0;
  padding:10px;
}
.slider:before {
  transform:rotate(180deg);
}
.slider:after {
  left:auto;
  right:0;
}
.slider > div {
  flex: 0 0 100%;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
  font-size:200%;
  color:#FFF;
  transition:margin-left .3s;
}
```

```html
<div id="sliderbox">
        <div class="slider" data-slider-paused="true">
        
        




          <div><img src="../aa7.jpg"/><img src="../aa2.jpg" style="margin-left:10%"/><img src="../aa5.jpg" style="margin-left:10%"/></li></div>
          <div><img src="../aa1.jpg"/><img src="../aa3.jpg" style="margin-left:10%"/><img src="../aa8.jpg" style="margin-left:10%"/></div>
          <div><img src="../aa6.jpg"/><img src="../aa9.jpg"style="margin-left:10%"/><img src="../aa12.jpg"style="margin-left:10%"/></div>
          <div><img src="../aa4.jpg"/><img src="../aa11.jpg"style="margin-left:10%"/><img src="../aa13.jpg"style="margin-left:10%"/></div>
         
        </div>
        
        </div>
```

Comment: `slide(this);` is wrong. I don't know what else may be wrong, but that is a bug. Accessing `this` in a freestanding function refers to the global window object, in sloppy mode, or `undefined` in strict mode. In events it may be the targeted object but given that multiple objects may respond to a single event, it is dangerous. I recommend you add `"use strict";` to the top of the file.

Comment: Thank you for a peek. When I remove `slide (this) ;`, The slider stops working. Do you have any other solution for this? Where exactly do I add `"use strict";`?

Comment: Add `"use strict";` as the first line of the JavaScript file. Instead of `slide(this)` use something like `slide(e.target)`. Consider how it is called in `slideAll` and call it in the same manner.

Comment: Ok thank you, the slider works as normal! I will edit the upper code and remove the mistake. I still don't know how to create that bottom .div, that content changes upon image clicking on the slider.